# How to display jquery datepicker value of Check In plus 1 in value of Check Out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

My code is like thi :

```
jQuery("#datepicker_checkin").datepicker({ 
    minDate: 0, 
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
}); 
jQuery("#datepicker_checkout").datepicker({ 
    beforeShow : function()
    {
        jQuery( this ).datepicker('option','minDate', jQuery('#datepicker_checkin').val() );
    } , 
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
}); 
jQuery("#datepicker_checkin").on('change', function() {
    jQuery("#datepicker_checkout").val(jQuery('#datepicker_checkin').val());
    jQuery("#datepicker_checkout").datepicker({ 
        beforeShow : function()
        {
            jQuery( this ).datepicker('option','minDate', jQuery('#datepicker_checkin').val() );
        } , 
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    }); 
});
```

Demo is like this : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/RxTax/296/)

I describe like this :

If I select textfield of check in then textfield of check out will display value of checkout + 1

For example :

If Check In = 2016-02-26 Then Check Out = 2016-02-27

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: try this mate http://jsfiddle.net/RxTax/293/

Comment: @guradio,  I update my question

Comment: i think fiddle covers it?dont you think?

Comment: @guradio, What do you mean?

Comment: did you check the fiddle?

Comment: @guradio, Yes, I did. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$(function() {
  $( "#check-in" ).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function() {
        var checkOutDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        checkOutDate.setDate(checkOutDate.getDate() + 1);
        $( "#check-out" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", checkOutDate );
        $('#check-out').datepicker('setDate', checkOutDate);
    }
  });

  $( "#check-out" ).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```

Comment: I d'ont understand what you really want. This code display the check-in date + 1 in the check-out input on select and set it as min date. This is your question. Am I wrong ?

Comment: No worries @samueltoh. Glad I helped.

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652796/why-multiple-datepicker-not-working/39652870#39652870

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.pickupDate').change(function() {
  var date2 = $('.pickupDate').datepicker('getDate', '+1d'); 
  date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1); 
  $('.dropoffDate').datepicker('setDate', date2);
});
```

Adding +1d as per give example hope this will help you.